# Animating progression bars on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a multi step form with a progression indicator but I am struggling to animate the progress bar, I want a simple animation which on the click increases the width from 0 to 100.

I have created a replica of what I am working with here: https://jsfiddle.net/1zb9p8xo/

Here is my code too:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
    $('#progressbar li.active').next().addClass('active');
    if ($('#progress')) {};

  });

  $('.previous').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');
    $('#progressbar li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
  });
});



$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
  });
  $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
      $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#helpdeskform {
  position: relative;
}
#helpdeskform .field2,
.field3 {
  display: none;
}
#helpdeskform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#progressbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  counter-reset: step;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #f6f6f6!important;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  color: #f6f6f6;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  width: auto;
  color: transparent;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
}
#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #69bd45;
  margin-left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="helpdeskform" action="process.php" method="post">

  <!-- Progress Bar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active first" style="width: 33.33%;"></li>
    <li class="second"></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
  </ul>

  <fieldset class="field1 current">
    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>
    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />
    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button nextOne" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="field2">
    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>
    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />
    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button nextTwo" value="Next" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="previous" />
    <button>submit</button>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="field3">
    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>
    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />
    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="previous" />
    <button>submit</button>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way. Have a single element and animate the width

Comment: Hm this is where im getting confused I think, so switch them around you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a separate element for each step in the progress bar, just use a single element, and animate it's width:

```
  <!-- Progress Bar -->
  <div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
```

and style it with a bit of CSS:

```
#progressbar .progress {
  height: 20px;
  background: #69bd45;
  width: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

Now let's take a look at the JS for it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Number of steps in all
  var steps = 3;

  //Current step
  var current = 1;

  //progress element
  var progress = $('#progressbar .progress');

  //Function to update progress bar's value
  function updateProgress() {
    progress.css("width", 100 / steps * current + "%");
  }

  //Call once on page load to set the initial value
  updateProgress();



  $('.next').click(function() {

    current++;

    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');

    updateProgress();

  });

  $('.previous').click(function() {
    current--;
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');

    updateProgress();
  });
});
```

If you're familiar with JS, it's quite simple. First I declare the number of steps you want to have, and a variable to hold the current step. Then I made a simple function to change the progress bar width based on the current step.

After that, all you have to do is set the current step variable to whichever step you want to show, then call `updateProgress()`.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydp9z2ka/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Number of steps in all
  var steps = 3;

  //Current step
  var current = 1;

  //progress element
  var progress = $('#progressbar .progress');

  function updateProgress() {
    progress.css("width", 100 / steps * current + "%");
  }

  updateProgress();



  $('.next').click(function() {

    current++;

    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');

    updateProgress();

  });

  $('.previous').click(function() {
    current--;
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');

    updateProgress();
  });
});



$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
  });
  $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
      $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#helpdeskform {
  position: relative;
}

#helpdeskform .field2,
.field3 {
  display: none;
}

#helpdeskform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#progressbar .progress {
  height: 20px;
  background: #69bd45;
  width: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="helpdeskform" action="process.php" method="post">



  <!-- Progress Bar -->
  <div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>



  <fieldset class="field1 current">

    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>

    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />

    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button nextOne" value="Next" />

  </fieldset>


  <fieldset class="field2">

    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>

    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />

    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button nextTwo" value="Next" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="previous" />
    <button>submit</button>

  </fieldset>



  <fieldset class="field3">

    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>

    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />

    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="previous" />
    <button>submit</button>

  </fieldset>




</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".button").click(function(){
   $(".bar").animate({
     width: "+=50px"
    },"fast");  
  })
})
```

```css
.bar{
  width:0px;
  height:15px;
  background-color:#00FF00;
  display:inline-block;
}

.button{
  padding:5px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">

</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="button">
Next
</div>
```

And you could improve that based on your needs.(set a max width, slower speed, etc.)

Comment: But has zero reference to what I am doing?

Comment: You asked for a way to animate the width of a progress bar.  Here it is. Oh, sorry you were expecting for us to write all your code for you....

Answer (score 1):

The progress bar in *forward direction* can easily be fixed by replacing `width: auto` in `#progressbar li:before` with `width:0` - see demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
    $('#progressbar li.active').next().addClass('active');
    if ($('#progress')) {};

  });

  $('.previous').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');
    $('#progressbar li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
  });
});



$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
  });
  $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
      $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#helpdeskform {
  position: relative;
}
#helpdeskform .field2,
.field3 {
  display: none;
}
#helpdeskform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#progressbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  counter-reset: step;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #f6f6f6!important;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  color: #f6f6f6;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  width: 0;
  color: transparent;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
}
#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #69bd45;
  margin-left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="helpdeskform" action="process.php" method="post">
  <!-- Progress Bar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active first" style="width: 33.33%;"></li>
    <li class="second"></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
  </ul>
  <fieldset class="field1 current">
    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>
    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />
    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button nextOne" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field2">
    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>
    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />
    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button nextTwo" value="Next" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="previous" />
    <button>submit</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field3">
    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>
    <!-- Input -->
    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />
    <!-- Controls -->
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="previous" />
    <button>submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: thats perfect - exactly what i was wanting to achieve

Comment: what happens if you press next again before the first animation ends?

Comment: @danjbh It's definetely not perfect. The animation isn't smooth if you click the button twice. Also it doesn't animate when you click previous button.

Comment: yes, that is an issue.. ideally as @JacobGray points out, a *better design* would be to use only a *single element* for the progress bar instead of 3...

Comment: But _why_ would you use multiple elements like that? It greatly over-complicates it, makes a mess, and is simply bad practice, especially when it's so easy to just create one with a single element.

Comment: @JacobGray what would you do?

Comment: @danjbh see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
use bootstrap progress bar 

<div class="progress">   
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"    
aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">    
<span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>      
</div>
</div>

you can change the width based on setting the value style="width:70%"at each step
```

find info athttp://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Comment: I dont want to use Bootstrap its overkill for my project

Answer (score 0):

Use a single element to keep track of the progres

```js
$("#next").on("click", function() {
    var width = $("#progress").width();
 $("#progress").animate({"width": "+=50"});
    if (width > 350) {
        $("#next").hide();
    }
});

$("#prev").on("click", function() {
    var width = $("#progress").width();
 $("#progress").animate({"width": "-=50"});
    if (width < 350) {
        $("#next").show();
    }
    if (width <= 70) {
        $("#prev").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
#btn-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#progress {
  width: 33%;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="progress">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="btn-group">
  <button id="next">Next</button>
  <button id="prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need actually to make three separate fieldsets. You can easily hold everything in a one single div. Check it out!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var times = 0;
  $('.next').click(function() {
    if (times < 2) {
      $('.progressbar').animate({
        width: "+=33.33%"
      }, 500);
      times++;
    }
    if (times > 0) {
      $('.submit, .previous').fadeIn();
    }
    if (times > 1) {
      $('.next').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $('.previous').click(function() {
    if (times > 0) {
      $('.progressbar').animate({
        width: "-=33.33%"
      }, 500);
      times--;
    }
    if (times < 1) {
      $('.submit, .previous').fadeOut();
    }
    if (times < 2) {
      $('.next').fadeIn();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progressbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  counter-reset: step;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
  height: 30px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="helpdeskform" action="process.php" method="post">

  <div class="progressbar"></div>

  <div class="field2">

    <h2>Dashboard name</h2>

    <input type="text" name="dashboardName" placeholder="Dashboard name" />

    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button nextTwo" value="Next" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button hidden" value="previous" />
    <button class='submit hidden'>submit</button>

  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can animate the width of the `#progressbar` with the `.animate()` function.
First, you can comment out/remove the `$('#progressbar li.active').next().addClass('active');` and replace it with the following:

**For next**

```
$('#progressbar li.active').animate({
    width: '+=33.33%'
});
```

**For previous**

```
$('#progressbar li.active').animate({
    width: '-=33.33%'
});
```

Comment: That fails, add it into my jsfiddle and see it works on load but that is as far as it goes...

Comment: I added it to your fiddle and it works fine. If it doesn't work in your local copy, you've left something out of your example.